# _pickle.PicklingError:Could not serialize object:RuntimeError while using foreachPartition pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the following error when using **foreachPartition**. I don't get an error when I use the **collect()** command, but when I use **foreachPartition or foreach** it gives an error.

Error messages:
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063

**Pyspark code:**

```
**I don't add libraries and above code**

def raw_data_partition(partition):

    df_cache = cache_data_test.cache_data  # dataframe in a different pyspark file
    for row in partition:
        process_row(row,df_cache)

def process_kafka_data(x,epoch_id):
    **x.rdd.foreachPartition(raw_data_partition)**

foreachBatch_df = kafka_mapping_df.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(process_kafka_data) \
    .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds') \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/enc_spark_location") \
    .start()

foreachBatch_df.awaitTermination()
```

I am using Spark version 3.2 , I have a single server, I use three workers on a single server. Can you help me?